# Retain only list of jsonPaths from a given json

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

I have a JSON and a list of jsonPath strings. I want to remove everything from the JSON and only retain the list of jsonPaths I have. I am using [Jayway's JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library

say my jsonPaths are:

1. `$.c`
2. `$.b[?(@.name=='ironman')]`

and my JSON is

```
{
    "a":"1",
    "b":[
        {
            "name": "ironman"
        },
        {
            "name": "thor"
        }
    ],
    "c": {
        "d":{
            "e": "nested"
        }
    }
}
```

I want my resulting JSON to be

```
 "b":[
        {
            "name": "ironman"
        }
    ],
    "c": {
        "d":{
            "e": "nested"
        }
    }
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Your desired resulting JSON is not valid JSON unless you add `{ }` around it.

Comment: Criteria #2 simply selects the `b` node, it does not filter the content, so `{ "name": "thor" }` will not be removed. I don't think what you're asking can be done.

Comment: I noticed you never accepted or upvoted an answer, please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers & https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking for a JSON Transformation; often [JOLT](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) is suggested for this in Java.

Using the Shift/Remover Operation we can do something like this:

```
[
  // Summary : Filter the "b object" by a specific name:ironman.
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "b": {
        // loop thru all the elements array
        "*": {
          "name": {
            // loop thru each element of the array
            // if the value in the name item is "ironman"
            // grab the whole "object" and write it out to the new b array.
            // The "@2" means go up the tree 3 levels (0-based) and grab what is there
            "ironman": {
              "@2": "b[]"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "c": "c"
    }
  }
]
```

Which creates the requested output.

You can test this online with your input here in the [JOLT online demo](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception).

Further reading:

- https://medium.com/@aleemraja95/jolt-json-to-json-transformation-library-71e118459198